# Evaluate a borrowed boolean

Tags: rust

Is there any work around this?

Is it possible to evaluate a borrowed boolean? I'm quite new to rust so I probably didn't used the right terminology.

```
fn control(map: &[bool;5]) -> bool {
    let mut hold = false;
    for n in map.iter() {
        if n {
            hold = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    hold
}
```

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63983390/edit) to include the full error message from the compiler.

Comment: Do you want to ask if it is possible to evaluate a borrowed boolean or fix your code? How is it related?

Comment: @KamilCuk It was more about understanding why that wasn't or how to make it possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply dereference `n` as in `if *n {` and it will compile. `n` is a `&bool` in your example, `*n` gives you a `bool`, which the compiler expects.

The shorter version of `control` would be

```
fn control(map: &[bool]) -> bool {
    map.iter().any(|e| *e)
}
```

The above takes a borrowed slice (`&[bool]`) instead of a fixed-size array as an input parameter; this is strictly more powerful since all arrays can be borrowed as a slice. The loop in your version is folded into the `any()` method that all iterators provide.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you explain what does referencing means?